# PHP | How do I prevent duplicated/repeated array elements in a associative array/multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, hook

I am working on creating a plugin system for my website. Everything works great, except the fact that I get multiple of the same elements in my `$hooks` array. How do I prevent this? I have tried using `array_unique()` but that did not solve the problem. Is there a problem with my code structure or a function I need to use?

Var Dump ($hooks):

```
array(1) { 
  ["test"]=> array(0) { } 
} 

array(2) { 
  ["test"]=> array(0) { } 
  ["hello"]=> array(0) { } 
} 

array(3) { 
  ["test"]=> array(0) { } 
  ["hello"]=> array(0) { } 
  ["bye"]=> array(0) { } 
} 

Hello World!
```

**index.php**

```php
<?php

include('hooks.php');

$hook = new Phoenix\Hooks\Hooks();

$hook->register_action('test');
$hook->register_action('hello');
$hook->register_action('bye');

$hook->hook('test', 'test_func');

function test_func(){
    echo "Hello World!";
}

?>
```

**hooks.php**

```php
<?php 

namespace Phoenix\Hooks;

class Hooks
{

public $hooks;

    function __construct(){

        $this->hooks = array(); //Hooks array.

    }

public function hook($where, $callback){

    if(isset($this->hooks[$where])){
        foreach($this->hooks as $hook_name=>$args){
            if($hook_name == $where){
                call_user_func_array($callback,$args);
        }
    
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

    public function register_action($where, $args=array()){
        if(!isset($this->hooks[$where])){
            $this->hooks[$where]=$args;
            var_dump($this->hooks);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: They’re a phoenix, they’re gonna come back! (sorry, couldn’t resist). Your hook method is much simpler now, and looks like you’re making good progress :)

Comment: By definition, you cannot have duplicate/repeated elements in an associative array.  You provide a key, it will retrieve the value.  One value.  If you see different values it is because you changed the value between references.